# C: OR-Compare several variables to match a certain value

Tags: c, compare

**What would be the correct C-expression for this pseudocode?**

*If( (value1 OR value2 OR value3) == sizeof(array) ) then...*

**It seems, my approach isn't working properly:**

```
if( (LED->index_red || LED->index_green || LED->index_blue) == sizeof(pwm_table)/sizeof(uint8_t) )
```

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: You have to OR 3 equality conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way (well, it would compile but would compare 0 or 1 to your value, which isn't what you want).

You have to perform 3 ORed equality tests:

```
if ((LED->index_red == (sizeof(pwm_table)/sizeof(uint8_t))) || 
    (LED->index_green == (sizeof(pwm_table)/sizeof(uint8_t))) || 
    (LED->index_blue == (sizeof(pwm_table)/sizeof(uint8_t)))) {...}
```

While you're at it, if you know which condition is the most likely to be true, put that first in your expression, since logical OR short-circuits the other tests so your code will be faster.

BTW don't worry about the division cost, it's done at compile time.